# Stride in Conv2D

Tags: theano

Does `conv2d` or any other way by which we can form CNNs support stride, i.e., the amount of moving the filter over the input? the default value of stride for normal 2D convolution is 1 but I would like to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `T.nnet.conv2d` has a parameter `subsample` which permits you to do this.